# Safely removing C++ hidden virtual warning

Tags: c++, virtual, static-assert

I'm getting a compilation warning from Sun C++ 5.10 compiler about a hidden virtual method in some existing code that I'm changing. For whatever reason, the author has not implemented an override of the function for a given data type. I've recreated the situation here:

```
// First the data types
struct Shape {};
struct Square : public Shape {};
struct Circle : public Shape {};
struct Triangle : public Shape {};

// Now the visitor classes
struct Virtual
{   
    virtual ~Virtual() {}

    virtual void visit( Square& obj ) {}
    virtual void visit( Circle& obj ) {}
    virtual void visit( Triangle& obj ) {}
};

struct Concrete : public Virtual
{   
    void visit( Square& obj ) {}
    void visit( Circle& obj ) {}
};

int main()
{   
    Concrete myConcrete;

    return 0;
}
```

The `Concrete` class does not implement `void visit( Triangle& obj ) {}` and this is causing the following error message:

```
"pv_block.cpp", line 20: Warning: Concrete::visit hides the virtual function
Virtual::visit(Triangle&).
```

The code works fine but it would be nice to remove this warning message. I'd like therefore to implement the function so that the compiler is satisfied but in such a way that it cannot be used - preferably detected at compile time - since it's clearly not necessary at present.

Is there a way to implement a compile assertion to allow compilation but prevent use? I don't have access to either Boost or C++11.

Comment: Can you not add it as a private method to the concrete class?

Comment: @Lieuwe, you can't really hide virtual methods. It might prevent someone from calling it, but in the case where you use a reference to Virtual, you pass right by the access restrictions.

Comment: @Lieuwe The reason `Concrete` doesn't implement it is because it is content with the implementation in `Virtual`, not because it doesn't want anyone to call it.  Declaring and defining it in `Concrete` will break this.

Comment: @JamesKanze - an instance of `Concrete` cannot `visit` a `Triangle` directly. The only way is to do this is to upcast the `Concrete` instance to `Virtual`: `<static_cast><Virtual&>(myConcrete).visit(myTriangle);`.

Comment: @DavidHammen And why do you think you have the base class?  The visitor pattern *only* visits through the base class, and the fact that the hiding hasn't caused problems during execution is doubtlessly due to the fact that all calls are in fact through a reference or a pointer to the base class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why would you want to prevent use? Even if you (somehow) do prevent it so that the following (A) fails to compile:

```
Triangle t;
Concrete x;
x.visit(t);
```

the following (B) will still work:

```
Triangle t;
Concrete x;
static_cast<Virtual&>(x).visit(t);
```

So IMO, it doesn't make sense to try to prevent it from being called. I would solve the warning by adding a *using declaration* into the `Concrete` class, like this:

```
struct Concrete : public Virtual
{ 
    using Virtual::visit;
    void visit( Square& obj ) {}
    void visit( Circle& obj ) {}
};
```

This will silence the warning, and enable (A). But I don't believe it's wrong to enable (A) in this case.

Comment: The `using Virtual::visit` is a excellent solution---I wish I'd thought of it.  It shuts up the compiler, and documents in `Concrete` that you do want the default implemenatations from `Virtual` (although a normal C++ programmer should realize this without any documentation).

Comment: @Agnew: The function currently doesn't exist so can't be used. I don't want to create something that isn't needed, especially if further down the line it causes problems if someone then tries to use it. So in that sense, I want to continue preventing use. However, I do want to avoid the compiler warning and preferably not just by turning it off.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't necessarily agree with your design; I think the warning is valid and should be heeded as an example to reconsider. However, if this is what you want to do, you can just put the declaration in there and change the access to protected or something.

```
struct X {
   virtual void f() {}
   virtual void f(int) {}
};

struct Y : public X {
   virtual void f() {}
   virtual void f(int);
};

int
main() {
   Y y;
   y.f(10);
}

undefined reference to `Y::f(int)'
```

Comment: By definition, a virtual function is "potentially evaluated" (the standardese term for used) unless it is pure virtual.  So you must provide an implemenation of `f(int`.

Comment: Meaning it "must" be implemented. :)

Comment: @dans3itz: It's not my design as such, it's an existing piece of code that I've got to make some unrelated changes to. It probably could use a bit of an overhaul but that's outside the scope of what I'm doing. However, it is generating quite a few warnings - of which this is one - which are obscuring the compile output and I''d like to tidy them. I think you're right that making it private / protected is probably the best way to go.

Comment: @Component10 I don't think so.  That would change the semantics of the class, and probably break client code.  In the case of the visitor pattern, providing default implementations of functions in the base class, so the user doesn't have to implement all of the functions, is a common idiom.  The compiler is wrong to warn about it.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Agreed now - especially having seen Agnew's `using` solution. Out of interest GCC doesn't warn about this at all.

Comment: @Component10 - gcc will warn about this if you enable the compiler option `-Woverloaded-virtual`.

Answer (score 1):

The only real solution is to disable the compiler warning.
Presumably the base class provides a default implementation, and
the concrete class is happy with it.  Otherwise, you can provide
an implementation which forwards to the default implemenatation
in the base class:

```
void Concrete::visit( Triangle& obj ) { Virtual::visit( obj ); }
```

Personally, I find this to be excess verbiage, and would rather
avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like therefore to implement the function so that the compiler is satisfied but in such a way that it cannot be used - preferably detected at compile time - since it's clearly not necessary at present.

One way to do this is to declare `Concrete::visit(Triangle&)` as private:

```
struct Concrete : public Virtual
{   
   void visit( Square& obj ) {}
   void visit( Circle& obj ) {}
private:
   void visit (Triangle& obj);
};
```

Note the lack of an implementation. This eliminates the compiler warning, but does so at the expense of changing the compile-time error that currently results from `myConcrete.visit(myTriangle)` into a link-time error.

Even with this declaration, it's still possible to have a `Concrete` object `visit` a `Triangle` object by casting the `Concrete` object to the parent class: `static_cast<Virtual&>(myConcrete).visit (myTriangle)`. This is a problem, and a very big one. The code as it stands violates the Liskov substitution principle.

It's probably better to use the `using` solution proposed by Angew. Now the class design comes closer to obeying Liskov substitution. Note that there is still a problem with regard to Liskov substitution with regard to `static_cast<Virtual&>(myConcrete).visit (mySquare)` (and `myCircle`).